# whats the reason for this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Helloworld<wrong mname:Helloworld>

Tags: java

after solving the problem of the"could not find or load main class Hello" error...I faced this prob again after running the program(I use textpad)
the code is:

```
 class HelloWorld {  
    public static void main (String args[]) {  
    System.out.println(“Hello World!”);  
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 13):

Your class is named HelloWorld, your file is named Helloworld.java with a lower-case 'w'.

They need to be the same, including the case.